# Testing of data communication between the RPi3 bluetooth and HC05 BTM

Tags: python, pi-3, bluetooth, serial

I have connected my HC05 using TTL on my laptop.

Another side I have turn on my onboard bluetooth in Raspberry pi3.

I have python code for RPi3 communicate with my HC05.

Pairing is done using HC05 password

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate = 9600)
print ser.readline()
```

when I am checking board onboard bluetooth connection on RPi3 using dmesg | grep tty

```
smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:AA:0D:73 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:ProFont6x11 logo.nologo
```

when I am running my code its waiting for response on long time at RPi3.

I don't receive any error ,but whatever data I am sending to RPi3 through HC05 on terminal ,RPI3 cant receive

socket based communication is better or serial port based communication on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have tested with this code and Raspberry pi3 on board bluetooth receives data from HC05

```
from bluetooth import *
import time
bd_addr = "00:14:01:21:15:96"
port = 1
sock = BluetoothSocket (RFCOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr,port))
print 'waiting'
while 1:
        data = sock.recv(10)
        print data
        time.sleep(2.0)
        #tosend = raw_input()
        #if tosend != 'q':
        #        sock.send(tosend)
        #else:
        #        break

sock.close()
```